# Get Data From 2 Tables in One Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve data for my notification system. I have three tables. One table (notifications) holds the actual information for the notification itself. I have two other tables to keep track of who gets certain notifications. There are two types of notifications, user and global. A global notification goes to all users while a user notification only goes to specific users. For this I have two tables, notifications_users and notifications_global. The table structures are below:

- notifications (id, title, url, start, end)
- notifications_users (notification_id, user_id, viewed)
- notifications_global (notification_id, user_id, viewed)

What I want to do is to grab the notification title and url (from notifications table) along with the viewed value for all notifications that go to a specific user from both notifications_users and notifications_global tables. Would a UNION query be the best option here? I thought about just separating the queries but then I have two different arrays to loop through in my PHP script which I do not want. There has to be a way to grab all of this data with one query into one array. The following gives me an empty set:

```
SELECT notification.title, notification.url
FROM notifications
    RIGHT JOIN notifications_users ON notifications.id = notifications_users.notification_id 
    RIGHT JOIN notifications_global ON notifications.id = notifications_global.notification_id 
WHERE notifications_users.user_id = 11508 AND notifications_global.user_id = 11508;
```

Comment: Yes, a UNION is the right way to do this.

Comment: Just FYI, a search under the MySQL tag for "RIGHT JOIN" on SO currently returns ca. 1400 results - as compared with ca. 32000 result for "LEFT JOIN". Just sayin'.

Comment: Why does `notifications_global` have a `user_id` column if it goes to all users?

Comment: It was recommended to cut down on the size of the table to separate them. I guess I could just combine those into one table which would then make the query much easier. I'm not exactly sure how to do the UNION query.

Comment: Not an answer: are you sure you need 2 tables there? Can't you add simple global/non-global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have been over-complicating this a bit. I just wrote the two queries for each table separate and then put UNION between them. If anyone is interested, here is what I ended up going with.

```
(SELECT notification_id, notification_title, notification_url,  tbl_notifications_users_lookup.viewed
FROM tbl_notifications 
INNER JOIN tbl_notifications_users_lookup ON tbl_notifications.id = tbl_notifications_users_lookup.notification_id 
WHERE tbl_notifications_users_lookup.user_id = 11508)
UNION
(SELECT notification_id, notification_title, notification_url, tbl_notifications_global_lookup.viewed
FROM tbl_notifications 
INNER JOIN tbl_notifications_global_lookup ON tbl_notifications.id = tbl_notifications_global_lookup.notification_id 
WHERE tbl_notifications_global_lookup.user_id = 11508);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.title, a.url, b.viewed as 'User View', c.viewed as 'Global View'
FROM Notifications a
INNER JOIN Notifications_Users b
ON a.id = b.notification_id 
INNER JOIN Notifications_Global c
ON b.notification_id = c.notification_id
WHERE b.user_id = 11508 and c.user_id = 11508
```

Comment: I am getting an empty result set with this query. I'm going to try and play with the joins a bit. Thanks for the help.